# Checked box is correct or not?

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have `PHP` form. This `foreach` is execute multiple `checkedboxs`. I want know, User selected checked boxs `C_ID` `INSERT` to the database. This code not working properly.

```
    <?php
 if(isset($_POST['send'])){
      foreach($_POST['mod'] as $checkbox){
        $checkbox = $values[COURSE_ID];
        echo $checkbox . ' ';

        $date = date("Y-m-d"); 
        $sql= "INSERT INTO REG ( C_ID, REGISTERED, DATE) "
        . "VALUES ('".$values[C_ID]."', 'Y' ,'".$date. "')";
        DBQuery($sql);  
      } 
 }

echo "<form name=send method=post >";
   foreach($result1 as $value) {
    $checked = in_array($value, $selected) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="mod[]" value="' . $value[C_ID] .'"  ' . $checked . '>'. $value[TITLE] .'</input><br>';
   }
   echo "<button type=submit id=send name=send>send</button>";
   echo "</form>";
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php
 $result1 = array(
    array(
        'C_ID' => 1,
        'TITLE' => "test"
    ),
    array(
        'C_ID' => 2,
        'TITLE' => "test 2"
    )
 );
 $selected = array();

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
      foreach($_POST['mod'] as $checkbox){
        $date = date("Y-m-d"); 
        echo $sql= "INSERT INTO REG ( C_ID, REGISTERED, DATE) "
        . "VALUES ('".$checkbox."', 'Y' ,'".$date. "')";
        DBQuery($sql);  
      } 
 }

echo "<form name=send method=post >";
   foreach($result1 as $value) {
    $checked = in_array($value, $selected) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="mod[]" value="' . $value['C_ID'] .'"  ' . $checked . '>'. $value['TITLE'] .'</input><br>';
   }
   echo "<button type=submit id=send name=send>send</button>";
   echo "</form>";
   ?>
```

Comment: In mu code all data will display, but I can't submit it. I want submit selected data my friend.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this line is wrong - $checkbox = $values[COURSE_ID]; You are overwriting the checkbox information by a variable. I think it should be like this-

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
         foreach($_POST['mod'] as $checkbox){
           //$checkbox = $values[COURSE_ID];
           $courseId = $checkbox;
           echo $checkbox . ' ';

           $date = date("Y-m-d"); 
           $sql= "INSERT INTO REG ( C_ID, REGISTERED, DATE) "
           . "VALUES ('".$courseId."', 'Y' ,'".$date. "')";
           DBQuery($sql);  
         } 
    }

   echo "<form name=send method=post >";
      foreach($result1 as $value) {
       $checked = in_array($value, $selected) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
       echo '<input type="checkbox" name="mod[]" value="' . $value[C_ID] .'"  ' . $checked . '>'. $value[TITLE] .'</input><br>';
      }
      echo "<button type=submit id=send name=send>send</button>";
      echo "</form>";
```

?>